# How to store after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

How am I able to use the column after using groupby?
Let's say

```
x = df_new.groupby('industry')['income'].mean().sort_values(ascending = False)
```

would give:

```
"industry"        
telecommunications        330
crypto.                   100
gas                       100
.
.
.
```

I would like to store the top most income's industry name to some variable and use it for other queries, so here it would be `"telecommunications"`.
But doing x[0] would give 330...

also pls recommend a better wording for this question... don't know the right terminologies

Comment: I think you'll get more answers if you go through [your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8936041/jun?tab=questions) and accept answers that worked for you. ;)

Comment: Also @jun, I advise you to be meticulous about tag choices - initially for this question, you added only the `pandas-groupby` tag and no others, so I (and probably many others) didn't see it, because I'm not watching that tag. I watch the `pandas` tag. So definitely add as many appropriate tags as you can always.

Comment: sorry about that.. also thank you for adding the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby(...).XXX()` (where `XXX` is some support method, e.g. [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html), [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html), etc.) typical return **Series** objects, where the **index** contains the values that were grouped by. So you can use [`x.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.index.html):

```
>>> x.index
Index(['telecommunication', 'crypto', 'gas'], dtype='object', name='industry')
```

If you want to get index for the max/min value, you can use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html)/[`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
>>> x.idxmax()
'telecommunication'

>>> x.idxmin()
'crypto'

>>> x.index[2]
'gas'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert it into another dataframe using following code

```
x = df_new.groupby('industry')['income'].mean().sort_values(ascending = False).to_frame(name='mean').reset_index()
```